# Set the background images fit to any screen

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am developing a game using `cocos2d-x`. For setting the background image fit to my screen I used the following code, but it stretch the image please give advice.

```
bool AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
    CCDirector *pDirector = CCDirector::sharedDirector();
    pDirector ->setOpenGLView(CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView());
    CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView() ->setDesignResolutionSize(480, 320, kResolutionExactFit);
    pDirector ->setDisplayStats(false);
    pDirector ->setAnimationInterval(1.0 / 60);
    CCScene *pScene = SplashScene::scene();
    pDirector ->runWithScene(pScene);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

What I usually do is that I scale the image to screen size ratio. Below is some code for help.

```
CCSprite * sprite = CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName(spriteName);
sprite->setScaleX((winSize.width / sprite->getContentSize().width) * scaleXFactor);
sprite->setScaleY((winSize.height / sprite->getContentSize().height) * scaleYFactor);
```

scaleXFactor and scaleYFactor is the size that you want. if you want it to be full screen you can set it to 1.